# Ubuntu 17.04 upgrade asks me to choose trusted certificates

Tags: upgrade, 16.10, 17.04, certificates

I just started the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.10 to Ubuntu 17.04. It finished downloading and now `ca-certificates-Konfiguration` (in German) asks me to choose the certificates I trust.

I know the basics about CAs, but how do I know which ones are trustworthy? Is there a list or something? This seems awfully complex for a simple OS upgrade.

[image: Screenshot ca-certificates-Konfiguration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**
You can't really know which ones are trustworthy (and you're right that it is really much too complex to be asking the user to make a decision like that during upgrade). For most people it is best to allow Mozilla and Google to manage their respective trust stores, as they will ban or restrict any CAs found to be violating trust.

**Longer answer:**
Even the CAs which are supposedly the most "trustworthy" are regularly being found to have fallen short. For example, Google recently found that Symantec (a CA that most would assume to be a pillar of trustworthiness, especially since they own VeriSign) [had mis-issued over 30,000 certificates](https://arstechnica.com/security/2017/03/google-takes-symantec-to-the-woodshed-for-mis-issuing-30000-https-certs/) and committed major violations of the CABForum baseline requirements for CAs. Apparently this has been going on for years. Several other widely trusted CAs have similarly been found to be mis-issuing certificates or have had their trust compromised over the years ([CNNIC](https://arstechnica.com/security/2015/04/google-chrome-will-banish-chinese-certificate-authority-for-breach-of-trust/), [Comodo](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2623829/authentication/weaknesses-in-ssl-certification-exposed-by-comodo-security-breach.html), [Comodo again](https://threatpost.com/comodo-issues-eight-forbidden-certificates/115311/), and the now defunct [DigiNotar](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2511297/security0/diginotar-dies-from-certificate-hack-caper.html) are a few examples). It is becoming increasingly clear that the industry itself does not know how to accurately verify CA trustworthiness.

Also, understand that even CAs that are following the rules can be abused because they employ automated systems. For example, the fully automated CA Let's Encrypt [can be abused](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/14-766-lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates-issued-to-paypal-phishing-sites/) to make phishing sites look more trustworthy, and Let's Encrypt is not actually doing anything wrong. It's important to understand what is being asserted when you visit a "secure" site. Domain validation certificates (the most common) only assert that the person who registered the certificate also owns the domain, and that you have a secure connection to that domain's server. They don't assert anything about who the person or company operating that domain is.

If you are highly concerned about security and the possibility of lesser known CAs mis-issuing certificates, a good rule is to only trust CAs that are likely to issue certificates for the major sites you visit. For many people, this would be the major US and EU certificate authorities (here are the [top 10 from 2015](https://www.whichssl.com/top-10-ssl-certificate-providers.php), but keep in mind that Let's Encrypt is a big player now as well). You can later add trust for additional CAs as you may find the need to.